# Show <br/> in <p>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i replaced line feed characters with HTML line break as

`@post.description.gsub(/\n/, "<br/>")`

I am trying to show the output within

tags. But I see as follows:

```
Used, like new book<br/>New book costs $150<br/>Awesome book!
```

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use @post.description.html_safe in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `simple_format` for this as it will automatically convert new lines into breaks.

```
<%= simple_format(@post.description) %>
```

Comment: That was easy huh! Thanks a lot Ryan.

Comment: i found that, if i use simple_format, the css that i apply doesn't work for it.